# How do I create a macro to delete a table row based on a range of cells which all have identical values

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

First off, I'm sorry if this is answered somewhere else. I've searched through the site and can't find anything that seems to answer this question for my needs. I'm completely new to macros, this will be the first time I've tried implementing one. I attempted recording one myself but, as me coming here clearly shows, that got me nowhere.... I don't know how to write macros/VBA. I tried running Excel's "Record Macro" feature and then filtering data based on a cell's value and then deleting the rows with duplicate data, but that didn't work. When I ran the macro after that, it just filtered based on the value of the cell I had selected when I recorded the macro.

## Question

#### Part 1:

How do I create a macro in Excel that will filter my table so it only displays rows where all three columns (Northing, Easting, Elevation) are identical to the Northing, Easting, and Elevation of another row(s)?

#### Part 2:

Then, how do I make that same macro leave the first instance of the data but delete all rows containing the duplicate Northing, Easting, and Elevation? Again, all three must match the first instance. If only one or two of the columns match the first instance, I want it left because it's not an identical point.

#### Part 3:

I need the macro to search my entire table and perform this action on every row where the Northing, Easting, and Elevation data is identical to those three pieces of data in any other row. In every case, I need it to leave the first row that appears with the data but delete the rows containing the duplicate data.

Thank you in advance for any help you might be able to be! I'm pretty desparate to find a solution that will allow me to quickly get through these 7000 rows of data I have.

**I hope the sample below is not too long. I tried to give enough data to work with and have a good sample.**

[Excel file of the sample shown below](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rqgx5i9hz635jh1/_Test.xlsm?dl=0)

| Point # | Northing | Easting | Elevation | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 486942.990 | 2727277.620 | 817.090 | Example1 |
| 2 | 487232.950 | 2727284.613 | 787.460 | Example2 |
| 3 | 486879.180 | 2727517.621 | 803.425 | _NoDuplicate |
| 4 | 487155.702 | 2727564.718 | 794.449 | _NoDuplicate |
| 5 | 486942.990 | 2727277.620 | 817.090 | Example1 |
| 6 | 486942.990 | 2727277.620 | 817.090 | Example1 |
| 7 | 487222.142 | 2728277.351 | 789.665 | _NoDuplicate |
| 8 | 486471.604 | 2726417.279 | 780.678 | _NoDuplicate |
| 9 | 486522.528 | 2726483.133 | 785.644 | Example3 |
| 10 | 487265.671 | 2726869.400 | 780.803 | _NoDuplicate |
| 11 | 487232.950 | 2727284.613 | 787.460 | Example2 |
| 12 | 486942.990 | 2727277.620 | 817.090 | Example1 |
| 13 | 487232.950 | 2727284.613 | 787.460 | Example2 |
| 14 | 487232.950 | 2727284.613 | 787.460 | Example2 |
| 15 | 486942.987 | 2727277.621 | 817.092 | _NoDuplicate |
| 16 | 486942.990 | 2727277.620 | 817.090 | Example1 |
| 17 | 486916.976 | 2727960.190 | 792.667 | _NoDuplicate |
| 18 | 487136.935 | 2727629.030 | 788.643 | _NoDuplicate |
| 19 | 486522.528 | 2726483.133 | 785.644 | Example3 |
| 20 | 486522.528 | 2726483.133 | 785.644 | Example3 |

*Please take a look at the sample above. Hopefully it will help everything make sense and aid in the solution. (I've reduced it to only 20 rows of data, but the file I'm dealing with has around 7000. That's why I'm trying to find a more efficient way than manually searching for all the duplicates.)*

### Backstory (if interested/useful)

I'm a CAD drafter at a land surveying company. I'm currently drafting a job that multiple field crews had to work on at different times, meaning they had to import the previous crew's field data into their GPS equipment to make sure they weren't collecting the same data as the previous crew. **However, they made some errors in their import/export process and now I have thousands of field locates with identical northing, easting, elevation, and point description, but different point numbers.** *This will make more sense if you take a look at the small sample Excel file I've linked.*

After a couple days of manually searching hundreds of rows (out of around 7000) for the duplicate points and deleting all instances but the first, I've began to wonder if there's an easier way. That's what lead me here.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser. Please note that this is not a free code writing service. [please edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1699806/edit) to show us what you have tried and explain what the problem you encountered is. It's also a good idea to include sample data in your question and not as an external link.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad thank you for your response. I apologize for my lack of code, but I don't know how to write macros/VBA. All I tried was using Excel's "Record Macro" option to record what I did to filter data based on the content of a single cell, but it didn't help. And only filtered for the cell I had selected when recording it. In addition, I'm at a complete loss as to how I can get it to run in the entire table and delete all rows with duplicate data but leave the row with the first instance of the data. I linked the Excel file because I'm not sure how to format a table-style layout here.

Comment: That being said, I will do what I can to update my post to include the sample data and the code Excel gave me when I ran "Record Macro."

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I've added an in-line table to my post. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what to do about showing sample code since I haven't written any and don't know how to write it. See my first comment above for the only thing I knew to try (but didn't get anywhere near the results I need).

Comment: I would use a helper column to count the occurences (using `COUNTIFS`) and then filter on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just use the `RemoveDuplicates method?

*Note that in your sample workbook, your data is in a **Table** named `Table1` located on `Sheet1`.  You may need to edit the code to make changes if appropriate in your actual data.*

```
Option Explicit
Sub deDup()
    Dim LO As ListObject
Set LO = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
With LO.DataBodyRange
    .RemoveDuplicates Array(2, 3, 4), Header:=xlNo
End With
```

***Output from your sample data***
[image]

Comment: THIS should be the answer :-). LOL, I keep forgetting RemoveDuplicates exists, since my unsimplified code does more than just dedup, and was written before RD existed.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you so much!! This code does exactly what I need and is so much simpler than I expected the final code to be. You've saved me hours/days of manually going through each row and filtering my table to find the duplicates and delete them. This code will be irreplaceable for as long as I'm in the line of work. Seriously, thank you! :) (I definitely need to dive into VBA so I can help myself more in the future. Lol.)